# I am trying to create a program in which user enters a range of numbers, and i want to list down the prime numbers between the range

Tags: c++

// Program to find Prime number for a given range.

I have written the following code. So far the output that i am getting is not appropriate.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n1,n2,sum=0,i,j;
    cout<<"Enter the first number"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Enter the second number"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;
    int n3=(n1+1);
    for(i=n3; i<n2;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                sum=sum+1;      

            }





        }
            if(sum<3)
    cout<<i<<endl;

    }


}
```

Comment: Of course it is not appropriate. You declare a number prime when it has no more than 2 divisors between 1 and 10, inclusive, which has nothing to do with being prime (think numbers 121 and up).

Comment: Thanks.i understand that..but it is still not working

Comment: An act of understanding doesn't unbreak a broken program. You need to physically fix it.

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: @n.m.  dear...i had made changes and then commented.. i just didn't mention it bcz it thought ppl are smart enough.but i must say i am extremely disappointed!

Comment: @orbitcowboy thanks!! I did now its working well

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what you have done exactly? People here are smart but they can't read your mind. They need to see the code.

Comment: @n.m. cool..thanks for your advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is where you need to make changes. I'll break it down into separate function to help you understand better. You are iterating between the required range in the outer loop. Now you want to find out if the number in the current iteration is a prime number. Let's bring a function called `isPrime`  which checks if the number is prime.

```
bool isPrime(int x)
{
    bool flag = 1;
    for (int i=2;i<x;i++)
    {
        if (x%i == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This function checks if the number is prime. After adding this, your main function should look like this.

```
int main()
{

    int n1,n2,i;
    cout<<"Enter the first number"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Enter the second number"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;
    int n3=(n1+1);
    for(i=n3; i<n2;i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            cout <<i;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: downvote for int instead of bool, and for printf in a C++ program that uses cin and cout.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of inconsistencies that will lead to bugs. Also, think about what makes a number prime (if it is divisible by ONLY 1 and itself).

To help you out

1) for a number n between n1 and n2

2) check if n is divisible by any number between 2 to n-1 (unless the number is 2 then output 2)

3) if n is divisible by some other number between 2 to n-1 then it is not prime and it should not be listed. If it is not then output that number

This may minor optimizations you can run to not have to check every number's factors (such as if the number n is divisible by 2 and n != 2 then throw that number out)

ex) for the number 5 I would check if 5 is divisible by 2,3,4. if none of those are true then 5 is a prime number